# Where can I ask for help with web design?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've been designing the website for my software company for weeks now and I just can't seem to get the front page to look right. Is there a website by StackExchange where I can ask for advice and ideas for a my front page? I've looked at ProWebmasters and GraphicDesign but I wasn't sure about either of them.

Alternatively, if there isn't a stack exchange website that is suitable does anybody know any website at all where I could get this kind of help. The faster the better!

Comment: What kind of advice are you talking about, can you formulate some example questions?

Comment: @Pekka At the minute, I really need advice on whether I should use a slider or not on my front page and if so, what to put in it and how to make it blend in with the page etc.

Comment: Just ask on both, and see what comes back. You can't know unless you test it out.

Comment: @bobobobo Fair enough. I just thought I'd ask on the more appropriate one to avoid negative feedback, but if nobody really has an answer I guess that's all I can do

Comment: @bobobobo: that's really bad advice, cross-posting isn't something to be encouraged. Andy, I'm not familiar with those sites, but if you feel one of them might welcome that type of question, post there (on just one of them), or better, ask on the site-specific meta with an outline of your question. If your question's ok there, you're golden. If not, ask on the other site's meta.

Answer (score 5):

Web design questions can be asked on [Doctype](http://doctype.com/questions).

> Doctype is a free question and answer site for web designers. You can ask questions about CSS, HTML, web design and email design.

It's not an official Stack Exchange site (meaning it isn't owned by SE, and doesn't run the same code), but it was inspired by Stack Overflow.  It's also a member of the [League of (Web) Justice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/) (if that's still a thing).

Comment: I can so how it *was* inspired by Stack Overflow and it looks like it was very helpful, but emphasis on the past tense! It looks like I'll be waiting a very long time for help on that website. Unless I'm looking in the wrong place of course

Comment: Incidently, they've got a cool page design!

Comment: @bobobobo it might be cool but unfortunately I can't really copy that idea for my website simply because mine is an ecommerce website that sells software. Plus, I'm probably being awkward but I have a really good template that I want to use for loads of reasons, I'm just struggling with the content and how to format it.

Answer (score 5):

If your question is about usability-related issues (your comment about the slider makes me think it might be), you could try [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

Comment: UX is much more than usability :P. But yeah, this sounds potentially on topic on UX depending on the problem, but "advice or ideas" makes me leary as to whether it's something for SE's format altogether

Comment: UX is much more than usability, yes.  I was trying to focus on his question(s), rather than describe the whole scope of the site (which he can get from the FAQ there). :-)